# What happens when a SOAP fault occurs?

Tags: soap, error-handling

If there is a web service method like this:

```
object MyMethod()
{

  ..fault happens here.. 

  return someObject;
}
```

I want to know what (if anything) gets returned to the client from this method.  I know there will be SOAP fault XML generated, but what about **someObject**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault will be treated as an exception and the exception will be throwed, in this case, the someObject will not be delivered to the client. The client will receive the exception, and you must handle it. If you handle these exception on web service level, you can still return the someObject